# Ошибка подключения к Microsoft SQL Server - This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Использую PHP 5.6, все необходимые для работы драйвера скачал, пытаюсь выполнить следующий код

```
  $host = "";
  $conInfo = array("Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
  $con = sqlsrv_connect($host, $conInfo);

  if($con){
    echo "Success!";
  }else{
    echo "Fail..";
  }
```

Выводит Fail..Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

Comment: дак и проверьте `sqlsrv_errors`.

Comment: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86

Comment: ну дак не все драйвера поставили, значит :)

Comment: @YuriGo собственно Вы написали ответ на свой вопрос, загрузите и установите [драйвер Microsoft® ODBC 11 для SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Системные требования для sql php](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver).

Ошибка:

> This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.
>   Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
>   for x86

говорит о необходимости установки драйвера Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 для SQL Server.
[Страница загрузки](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/details.aspx?id=36434).